# Error 302 when installing rake gem

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, debian-lenny, rubygems, gem

i try to install **rake** on my clean lenny server, i get the following error:

```
Updating installed gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Found 302 (http://gems.rubyforge.org/latest_specs.4.8)
```

any advice here? thank you!

Comment: "Error, the content is found." What? Oh and wouldn't SO be a better place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the issue is that `gems.rubyforge.org` is the old gem server.  It now redirects to the new one is at `rubygems.org`.